# Unique keys in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, binary-trees

I'm studying for my finals and I can across this statement.

"For a fixed set of (unique) keys, any binary search tree containing those keys can
be converted to any other BST on the same set of keys via a sequence of left- and/or right-
rotations."

I'm interested in a proof. Does anyone know any references?

Comment: You can probably prove it by induction on the size of the tree. Have you tried?

Comment: Alternatively, think about what happens if you just apply right rotations until none are possible.  Which search tree do you end up at?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short method of transforming a BST $T_1$ into any other BST $T_2$ on the same set of keys, taken from notes written by [Doug Hogan at Penn State](http://test.scripts.psu.edu/users/d/j/djh300/cmpsc465/notes-4985903869437/solutions-to-some-homework-exercises-as-shared-with-students/3-solutions-clrs-13.pdf):

> Define the *right spine* of a BST as the root and all descendants of
>   the root that are reachable by following only right pointers from the
>   root. A *right-linear chain* is a BST that has all n nodes in the
>   right spine.
>
> Let $T'$ be the (unique) right-linear chain of $n$ keys.  Let $r = (r_1, r_2, ..., r_k)$ 
>   be a sequence of right rotations that transforms $T_1$
>   into $T'$, and let $r' = (r'_1, r'_2, ...,r'_{k'})$ be a sequence of
>   right rotations that transforms $T_2$ to $T'$.  We know there exist
>   sequences $r$ and $r'$ with $k, k' \leq n-1$, since a right rotation
>   adds exactly one node to the right spine.  For each right rotation
>   $r'_i$ let $l'_i$ be the corresponding left rotation.  Then, the
>   sequence $(r_1, r_2, ..., r_k,l'_{k'},l'_{k'-1}, ..., l'_2, l'_1)$
>   transforms $T_1$ to $T_2$ in at most $2n-2$ rotations.

...and [here's another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027726/is-it-always-possible-to-turn-one-bst-into-another-using-tree-rotations), which gives a nice recursive algorithm.

Google search terms: `binary search tree transform rotation proof`.